# Access ressource created from for_each module

Tags: module, terraform

**Context**

I create several instances of a kubernetes Service using following module.

variables.tf

```
variable "backends" {
  description = "List of backends"
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    k8s_namespace = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      name = "monitoring"
      k8s_namespace = "monitoring"
    },
    {
      name = "application"
      k8s_namespace = "application-ns"
    }
  ]
}
```

modules/k8s_services/main.tf

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "internal_lb" {
  metadata {
    name = "internal-lb-${var.name}"
    namespace   = "${var.k8s_namespace}"
    annotations = {
      "service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal" = "true"
      "service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet" = "snet-lb"
    }
  }
  spec {
    selector = var.selector
    
    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 8080
    }

    type = "LoadBalancer"
    
  }
}
```

as expected, I get those services in my plan. Nice.

```
  # module.k8s_services["application"].kubernetes_service.internal_lb will be created
  + resource "kubernetes_service" "internal_lb" {
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + status                 = (known after apply)
      + wait_for_load_balancer = true

      + metadata {
          + annotations      = {
              + "service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"        = "true"
              + "service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet" = "snet-lb"
            }
          + generation       = (known after apply)
          + name             = "internal-lb-application"
          + namespace        = "application-ns"
          + resource_version = (known after apply)
          + uid              = (known after apply)
        }

      + spec {
          + cluster_ip                  = (known after apply)
          + external_traffic_policy     = (known after apply)
          + health_check_node_port      = (known after apply)
          + publish_not_ready_addresses = false
          + selector                    = {
              + "app"         = "nginx"
              + "nginx/nginx" = "true"
            }
          + session_affinity            = "None"
          + type                        = "LoadBalancer"

          + port {
              + node_port   = (known after apply)
              + port        = 80
              + protocol    = "TCP"
              + target_port = "8080"
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

I want to take those ressources by adressing them as a backend in an azure appgateway. I try to generate several backend_addess_pool instances using a dynamic block as follows. Therefore I need the IP in the configuration block.

*side note: These nested loops to get the IP are working fine for a single k8s Service, where I define a `ressource "kubernetes_service" "internal_lb"` and address the Service instance like `kubernetes_service.internal_lb` as a 'normal' ressource.*

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "ag" {
...
  dynamic "backend_address_pool" {
    for_each = toset(var.backends[*].name)
    content {
      name = "backend-pool-${backend_address_pool.value}"
      ip_addresses = flatten([
        for s in module.k8s_services["${backend_address_pool.value}"].kubernetes_service.internal_lb.status : [
          for lb in s.load_balancer : [
            for ingress in lb.ingress : ingress.ip if ingress.ip != null
          ]
        ]
      ])
    }
  }
...
}
```

And I get these error messages:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on appgw.tf line 49, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "ag":
│   49:         for s in module.k8s_services["${backend_address_pool.value}"].kubernetes_service.internal_lb.status : [
│     ├────────────────
│     │ backend_address_pool.value is "application"
│     │ module.k8s_services is object with no attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

My question is:
How can I address these ressources to work on theire attribute values?

Comment: Though I didn't understand the complete context, I guess you are iterating over a list which is returned from a module output. In such cases, `terraform` recommends to use `map` wherein the keys are deterministic (must be known during plan) & values are dynamic which could be the values of list. Although, I don't think the error says something different. Could be that your module isn't returning any `outputs`..

Comment: @harshavmb the hint to go via module outputs helped me to find a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, it appears that `module.k8s_services` isn't returning any `outputs`.

Try adding `outputs` within that module so that they can be used by calling modules.